# Console application immediately exits after setting RedirectStandardOutput to true

Tags: c#, process

I have a Process that needs to update the console in realtime based on the output. But its not working. The console just opens and closes, and the Process runs in the background. I can not figure out what I am doing wrong. Here is my code:

```
private static StringBuilder sortOutput = null;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Process process;
    process = new Process();
    process.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\ffmbc\\ffmbc.exe";
    //process.StartInfo.Arguments = "-i new5830df.mxf -an ";
    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    sortOutput = new StringBuilder(""); 
    process.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(OutputHandler);
    process.Exited += new EventHandler(myProcess_Exited);
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    process.Start();
    process.BeginOutputReadLine();
}

private static void OutputHandler(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs outLine)
{
    string line;
    line = (outLine.Data.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine(line);
}

private static void myProcess_Exited(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Proccess Finished");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to call [`process.WaitForExit()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb4aw7b8.aspx) to block until the process exits.

Comment: When I add process.WaitForExit() the window stays open but does not update with the output. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Your Main() has exited, so the console closes.  You need to wait until the called program completed, before you exit your Main function.